# Why I can't aggregate setof jsonb in Postgres?

Tags: json, postgresql, aggregate, postgres-9.6

I am trying to convert `jsonb`-column into string, but after using `jsonb_array_elements` I can't find any function what could do anything useful with `setof jsonb` it returns.

```
SELECT string_agg( jsonb_array_elements(col), ':' ) 
FROM test_json_array 
WHERE id = 1;
```

ends with:

```
ERROR:  function string_agg(jsonb, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT string_agg( jsonb_array_elements(col), ':' ) FROM tes...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Using ARRAY-constructor or `array_agg` give another error:

```
$ SELECT ARRAY[ jsonb_array_elements(col) ] FROM test_json_array WHERE id = 1;
ERROR:  set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set

$ SELECT array_agg( jsonb_array_elements(col)) FROM test_json_array WHERE id = 1;
ERROR:  set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set
```

All I found googling around ended jsonb-part in `FROM`-clause, like:

```
SELECT string_agg( j.x, ':' )
FROM test_json_array tbl, jsonb_array_elements_text(tbl.col) AS j(x)
WHERE tbl.id = 1;
```

I'd like to have such aggregation together in `SELECT`-clause, but I can't understand, why it is impossible? Or is it?

Using Postgres 9.6

Comment: set returning functions should be used in the FROM clause, not in the SELECT list.

Comment: @stickybit I have tried `jsonb_array_elements_text()`, it did not change nothing. As sample data, the `col` has value `'["x","y","z"]'`, desired result would string "x:y:z";

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name from your comment I understand, this is fundamental, I just try to wrap my head around it, and understand, why?

Comment: A table is a set, so a set returning function is similar to a table. Would you expect to be able to use all rows of a table in the SELECT list? Putting such a function into the select list would be similar to `select t1.x1, select t2.x2 from other_table t2 from some_table t1`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ok, but table has 2 dimensions, so it is obvious, I can't aggregate it further without selecting from it. But function giving us back a set of array elements is one-dimensional (even if every element is object). So it could be open to further aggregation. Or?

Comment: A function returning a result set has two dimensions as well: rows and columns - admittedly, most set returning functions only return a single column, but still it's the same thing. https://rextester.com/YMKL91752

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I feel your explanations answer pretty well to my question already, so would you, please, form it as an answer too. I still lack simpler jsonb-array into array converting function, but this is design choise of Postgres developers.